# Live traffic on port via snmp and discrepancies

Tags: performance, snmp, utilization, juniper

Iam trying to get data from HP switches and Juniper firewalls and its port via snmp.

I am looking for the way how to analyze live traffic on port so I can create a graph of utilization of the ports like on Solarwinds or Observium.

So far I have the results I am getting are from the formula on [How to calculate traffic on cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/8141-calculate-bandwidth-snmp.html)

It works fine, however, every couple of readings I get abnormal speeds. I.e. for a virtual interface on the firewall, which is limited to 4MB I get 20+ MB every now and then.

I have a cron job which polls the devices every 5 minutes so the formula is using 300 seconds as a delta of time.

So the question is, is it possible for a port to be showing these abnormalities or am I doing something wrong? Any insight would be amazing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using **ifTable** defined in **RFC1213**. It is sort of outdated due to ifInOctets and ifOutOctets are defined as 32-bit counters. So they will overflow and reset real fast and you'll face abnormal results when this happens. I'd suggest switching to **ifXTable (IF-MIB)** where these counters are defined as **64-bit value**s.

Comment: Or handle the "counter rollover" in your code. Google it for others' algorithms.

Comment: Hey, This is now working as expected. I was using 64-bit values already but the formula in the article in my original post was not the same as the one used in observium. I have deleted the multiplication by 100 and iam getting same result now as observium/solarwinds :-) Thank you